# Understanding WCF

Tags: wcf

Could anyone point me to a resource that explains WCF with pictures and simple code snippets. I am tired of googling and finding the same "ABC" articles in all search results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WCF is a very complex technology that in my opinion is very poorly documented. It is incredibly easy to get up and running with, but the performance tuning to run a large scale app can be incredibly complicated and a lot of trial and error. One day everything is working fine and then you find out that only a single Channel is kept waiting for a new connection and that there is a config setting that you need to adjust on a custom binding to allow more channels to be waiting so that calls don't fail inbetween when a channel is used and the next channel is spun up.

In general Nicholas Allen's blog is a gold mine of information. However Windbg has been my best friend in trying to explain some very bizarre behavior coming from WCF.

Comment: +1 for: "WCF is a very complex technology that in my opinion is very poorly documented."

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a really simple example](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/11/29/an-introduction-to-wcf-for-device-developers.aspx).  It's specific to CE/Mobile devices, but the concept is no different PC to PC.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following two books to be really good for getting up to speed on WCF:

- Programming WCF Services (Lowy - O'Reilly)
- Pro WCF (Peiris, Mulder - Apress)

They both start with more of a conceptual description of WCF, so you understand the concepts and terms.  This is really useful, because it allows you to narrow any google searches to more specific concepts.

Answer (score 0):

And this is an article that breaks down [understanding WCF](http://debasishpramanik.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/understanding-wcf/) and why it was developed in a simple, bulleted list.